# Ratchet - The IO Server suddenly stop working

Tags: php, websocket, ratchet

I have run the ratchet IOServer on my server, everything works fine except it stop working randomly after a day.

```
$server = IoServer::factory(
    new HttpServer(
        new WsServer(
            new AppServer()
        )
    ),
    8082
);
$server->run();
```

Port is free to use, I am using the `supervisord` to control my daemon process. When I recheck whether the process is running or not, I can see the process is still there, but the Ratchet server basically could not be connected to anymore. it starts working properly by the following command

```
$ supervisorctl restart appserver
```

I have no idea what going on. In current situation, I have to restart it over again after 1 day

```
# supervisorctl

  appserver                      RUNNING   pid 29083, uptime 1 day, 2:03:20
```

(I have used the `forever` before, it gave me the same result)

Do I need to modify the duration of the ratchet server settings somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my server, there is a code which was using the database connection. I guess sometimes it dropped and the server is failed to continue. By running a script to restart the server every hour is my workaround.

Comment: yeah its happening to me to... restart fixed it.

Comment: How will you restart the server automatically??

Comment: I add a cron job to do it: 0 * * * * supervisorctl restart [my-server-name]